# Unhandled exception reading from X509CertificateStore

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm working with a really old project and moving it from on-prem to an azure VM running windows server 2016 and after the move we noticed an API endpoint returning Bad Gateway (502). I recreated the request using postman and noticed that I didn't even get a response back. After adding a bunch of logging i narrowed it down to the method below where it's suppose to read the security token from a certificate.
It seems like an unhandled exception occurrs just before the code which iterates each certificate but I can't seem to catch the exception using UnhandledExceptionEventHandler.
As far as I can see all the required certificates are in place. The one used here I even gave the user group "Everyone" full access just to just to eliminate that as a possible reason for the error
In reality this method is full of logging for each line of code but I've removed it for readability.

```
        private static X509SecurityToken GetSecurityTokenBySimpleDisplayName(string simpleDisplayName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(simpleDisplayName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("simpleDisplayName");
            try
            {
                AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
                currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
                using (X509CertificateStore store = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore))
                {
                    var isOpen = store.OpenRead();

                    int certIndex = -1;
                    /***** HERE IS WHERE IT CRASHES *****/
                    for (int i = 0; i < store.Certificates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (store.Certificates[i].SimpleDisplayName.ToLower().Equals(simpleDisplayName.ToLower()))
                            certIndex = i;
                    }

                    if (certIndex < 0)
                    {
                        throw new SecurityException("Certificate " + simpleDisplayName + " not found");
                    }

                    var token = new X509SecurityToken(store.Certificates[certIndex]);
                    return token;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Logging exception
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            // Logging exception

        }
```

The application event log gives this error:

- Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
- Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3383, time stamp: 0x5ddcba29
- Exception code: 0xe0434352
- Fault offset: 0x0000000000034c48
- Faulting process id: 0x3528
- Faulting application start time: 0x01d5f20898415d08
- Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
- Faulting module path: C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
- Report Id: 64f16b87-a524-4e0e-9ab9-d8295ce7b29b
- Faulting package full name:
- Faulting package-relative application ID:

How can I get a better idea of what's wrong?

Comment: You said Postman was NOT working.  Is that accurate?  Most times I see issues like this Postman works and the c# code does not work.  So first get postman working.  Then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request between working Postman and non working c#.  The default headers in c# are different from postman.  The Encryption settings seem to have change recently in the Net Library with 4.7 (and maybe 4.6).  A lot of people are having issues taking working code and upgrading to 4.7.  I think it has to do with encryption mode going from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Comment: If Postman doesn't work that the IP address has an issue.  You can't get to the GATEWAY.  The sniffer results should show the IP address (or hostname) that you are using.  If you are using IP then change the the hostname.  If DCHP is being used periodically the IP address of machine get changed.  So when DCHP is enabled always use the host name instead of IP.

Comment: I don't think Postman is the issue. The api endpoint has some quirks like when a specific date of birth is entered it will just return a success message. When i do that I get a response as I should but when doing this quirk I don't go into the method above, When I instead use real data that's when postman isn't getting a response and the logging shows that the request crashes at the comment /***** HERE IS WHERE IT CRASHES *****/

Comment: And we should guess what is the error? Pointing to a line where the code fails isn't enough. What about logging raised exception?

Comment: I agree it is not Postman.  But you need to get postman working before trying to use c#.  It will be easier to get api working with postman.  Postman you will be able to view the response and make changes easier.  So you first have to login to api with the data.  Then you need to get working with postman the request that returns data.  Finally take the working postman query and run with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The application pool needed to be set to "Enable 32-bit application" once that was in place it started working again